# How do I get the user profile picture of someone using the Telegram bot chat API?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm making a basic Control Panel for managing my Bot with PHP.

Basically I want to display the Profile picture / avatar of the user who is sending message to the bot.

However the user object has no photo_id, so is there way to get the user's avatar?

Answer (score 12):

You need to use [getUserProfilePhotos](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getuserprofilephotos) method, and then [getFile](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getfile).

For example:
[image: Awesome Telegram Bot]

Comment: getFile requires a file_path argument that is not returned from  getUserProfilePhotos. If I try to use the file_id as file_path ther I get a "NOT FOUND" error.

Comment: ok I fixed it!. You need to call getFile using file_id as argument , you will receive the file_path and then you can download the file using https://api.telegram.org/file/bot<token>/<file_path>